# Bash: Pattern Matching/Filename Expansion

Tags: bash, scripting, expansion

So, I'm leaning Bash scripting currently, and I'm a bit confused about the difference between pattern matching and file name expansion.

The [Bash Reference manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC36) reads:

> After word splitting, unless the `-f' option has been set (see section 4.3.1 The Set Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters`*', `?', and`['. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the pattern.

This to me suggests that the following should probably not do what we want:

```
if [[ $a == [cb]at* ]] ; then ...
```

In this case `[cb]at*` doesn't expand to a list of files beginning *cat* or *bat* as the above quote suggests, but acts more like a very limited regular expression.  Why?  When do the characters *?[ act like a regular expression instead of expanding to matched files in the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) interpret the tokens within the `[[ ... ]]` differently. It's a feature.